# rminer mining with more than one dependent variables

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I run the `mining` function from the `Rminer` package with more than one dependent variable?

In the case of one dependent variable(`BODout`) running is OK:

```
NNfit <- mining(BODout~pHin+Tin,WWTPout, method=c("holdout",2/3), model="svm",Runs=20)
```

but when `dep` is a data frame with two dependent variable (for example BODout and CODout) and `indep` is other variables which are independent, mining does not work:

```
NNfit <- mining(dep~indep, method=c("holdout",2/3), model="svm",Runs=20) 

Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: R dataframes do not have "dependent variables" and I only see a package named 'rminer' on CRAN. The `rminer::mining` function probably expects to evaluate the formula argument in the context of a data argument which you have not provided. Your question is incomplete and confusing in several respects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that method only allows for one response variable. Is there anything you  saw that led you to believe the method would work with more than one dependent variable? It's not so much the function itself as it is the underlying statistical method.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, i would like to make a NN model among a wastewater treatment plant input and output characteristic variables. my responses are BODout and CODout (output characteristics) and predictor variables are CODin, BODin, pHin  and TSSin (input characteristics) but I dont know to define a formula with two response variables in rminer, I think this capability should be provided because statistically we have some models with more than one response!

Comment: Well, just because a model exist, doesn't mean an implementation exists. If it did, i would have thought the package author would have shown an example. I might contact the package author and ask them.

Comment: Thanks again, let me know if you received answer from the author.

Comment: @MahdiHadi Sorry, I meant to suggest that you contact the author directly. Information is on [the CRAN Rminer page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rminer/index.html)